# Hanging writing objects when uploading in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am currently facing a weird issue that when I upload video in GitHub it takes ages to upload and then it fails. The video is small, it's only 6 MB and the limit while pushing is 100 MB.

```
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects:  83% (5/6), 3.78 MiB | 1024 bytes/s
```

Comment: Are you saying that pushing is faster when the file is not a video? Or is your internet connection just slow.

Comment: My connection is fast and it works fine when pushing files that not a video

Comment: Can you show us what it says when it fails?

Comment: @bk2204: I suspect it hasn't said anything yet, and instead the bit rate has just been dropping steadily. It's probably one of those badly behaved middleware boxes eating https connections. Moataz Emad: try using ssh instead of https for pushing.

Comment: The file is uploaded finally but it take long time to upload and Iam using ssh so I think it should upload fast and I'm sure that the connection is fast